# Azure Cloud Service for loop much slower in production than on localhost

Tags: c#, performance, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cloud-services

This particular piece of code for some reason runs much slower on production server (which is XL Azure Cloud Service) than on localhost. The worst thing is that this slowness is not consistent, i.e. it is slow most of the time, but sometimes it works fast. By slow I mean this piece of code takes 4.000ms to run on production (I know this because I'm using Azure AppInsights) , and only around 60ms on localhost. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Here's code (please note that this is only part of bigger method, but I'm sure that this part is slowest, everything else is much faster):

```
for (var i = 0; i < feedDeserialized.Length; i++)
{
RedisWorkoutItem workout;
bool hasRespected;
string username, fullName, profilePic;

// usersFromRedis is  an array of Dictonary <string,string>
var userRedis = usersFromRedis[i];
// workoutsFromRedis is just an array of objects - RedisValue object
var stringWorkout = workoutsFromRedis[i];
// just an array of objects - RedisValue object
var workoutComment = commentsFromRedis[i].HasValue ? commentsFromRedis[i].ToString() : "";

if (userRedis != null)
{
    profilePic = userRedis["ProfilePhotoUrl"].HasValue
        ? userRedis["ProfilePhotoUrl"].ToString()
        : "";
    fullName = userRedis["FirstName"] + " " + userRedis["LastName"];
    username = userRedis["UserName"].HasValue ? userRedis["UserName"].ToString() : "";
}
//code inside this else statement never happens
else
{
    var stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch2.Start();
    var user = databaseContext.Users.Find(feedDeserialized[i].UserId);
    profilePic = user.ProfilePhotoUrl;
    username = user.UserName;
    fullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
    stopWatch2.Stop();
    telemetryHelper.TrackEvent(_telemetryClient,
        "CreateRedisFeedViewModelAsync: Went to DB for user", stopWatch2.Elapsed);
}

if (stringWorkout.HasValue)
{
    workout = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RedisWorkoutItem>(stringWorkout);
    hasRespected = workout.UsersWhoRespected.Contains(userId);
}
//code inside this else statement never happens
else
{
    var stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch2.Start();
    var workoutGuid = Guid.Parse(feedDeserialized[i].WorkoutId);

    var workoutFromDb = await databaseContext.Trenings.FindAsync(workoutGuid);
    var routine = await databaseContext.AllRoutineses.FindAsync(workoutFromDb.AllRoutinesId);
    workout = new RedisWorkoutItem
    {
        Name = routine.Name,
        Id = workoutFromDb.TreningId.ToString(),
        Comment = workoutFromDb.UsersCommentOnWorkout,
        DateWhenFinished = workoutFromDb.DateTimeWhenTreningCreated,
        NumberOfRespects = workoutFromDb.NumberOfLikes,
        NumberOfComments = workoutFromDb.NumberOfComments,
        UserId = workoutFromDb.UserId,
        Length = workoutFromDb.LengthInSeconds,
        Points = workoutFromDb.Score
    };

    workoutComment = workoutFromDb.UsersCommentOnWorkout;


    hasRespected = databaseContext.TreningRespects
        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.TreningId == workoutGuid && r.UserId == userId) != null;

    stopWatch2.Stop();
    telemetryHelper.TrackEvent(_telemetryClient,
        "CreateRedisFeedViewModelAsync: Went to DB for workout", stopWatch2.Elapsed);
}

string workoutLength;

if (workout.Length >= 3600)
{
    var t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(workout.Length);
    workoutLength = $"{t.Hours:D2}:{t.Minutes:D2}:{t.Seconds:D2}";
}
else
{
    var t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(workout.Length);
    workoutLength = $"{t.Minutes:D2}:{t.Seconds:D2}";
}


listToReturn.Add(new FeedMobileHelper
{
    Id = feedDeserialized[i].Id.ToString(),
    UserId = workout.UserId,
    WorkoutId = feedDeserialized[i].WorkoutId,
    Points = workout.Points.ToString("N0", new NumberFormatInfo
    {
        NumberGroupSizes = new[] {3},
        NumberGroupSeparator = "."
    }),
    WorkoutName = workout.Name,
    WorkoutLength = workoutLength,
    NumberOfRespects = workout.NumberOfRespects,
    NumberOfComments = workout.NumberOfComments,
    WorkoutComment = workoutComment,
    HasRespected = hasRespected,
    UserImageUrl = profilePic,
    UserName = username,
    DisplayName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullName) ? username : fullName,
    TimeStamp = workout.DateWhenFinished,
    DateFormatted = workout.DateWhenFinished.FormatDateToHrsDaysWeeksString()
});
}
```

I cannot understand why this takes 4 seconds to complete on cloud service with 8 cores and 15 GB of RAM, especially because there is nothing fancy in here, no trips to database (as I noted in comments the "else parts" of code are never executed) or disc, everything is done in memory. And most of things in loop are done in constant time - O(1). Please can anyone help me to figure out what's problem here.

And one more thing, the API call which executes this part of code isn't called by 1000s of users at the same time, it is only called by me (I'm sure of this).

P.S.

feedDeserialized.Length is around 60

Answer (score 1):

First thought - are you deploying Debug or Release build to Azure Cloud Service? Release build is optimized and much faster. If you right click on your cloud service and choose `Publish...` you can select which build to deploy. Also, you might want to enable profiling (under advanced settings as part of the publish wizard) to see the slow parts of your application.